# Outlook push notification subscription error, ErrorInvalidParameter , verification failed The operation has timed out

Tags: outlook, push-notification, verification, outlook-calendar

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations#compare-streaming-and-push-notifications

I am trying to subscribe push notification for user calendar events (create, update).

I am stuck on point. (ref: above doc url)
Heading:-  Subscription process
Point# 3

Implementation in PHP (Laravel).
I successfully hit the api to subscribe push notification. but on my endpoint when I try to validate url it always retuning me bellow error.

My php (Laravel) code to validate url:-

return response($request->validationtoken, 200)
->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

Error Response:-
Array
(
[error] => Array
(
[code] => ErrorInvalidParameter
[message] => Notification URL 'https://fe6e2bee141e.ngrok.io/outlook-calendar/webhook?validationtoken=YmE1ODdiMzItODVmYy00YmI5LWJiZDgtMzViZGM0MGJkYzBj' verification failed 'System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Exchange.OData.Model.Notifications.PushNotification.PushSubscriptionCallbackUrlValidationHelper.SendRequestAndVerifyResponse(Uri callbackUrl, PushSubscription pushSubscription)'.
)

)

Anyone can guide me what is wrong and how to do it in proper way? (If you can able to provide me php code reference that will be great.)